# finding data's between two string in the large paragraph String in python

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string

In the document Readed string file which has datas like below:

doc_string = '''Unwanted_Strings(Un_wanted_Data)->'UNWANTED_DATA "22.1.10"\n/end FUNCTION\n/begin Za%adnwindter" /" SYBOLE_LINK AXINW_Pdroc_ScjfdS1 */\n /begin SER_SDVKHSDF\n   CDLWKJFL lfjd\n   dkjfJJJJJJJJJJJJk_lfkgj\n /end **/begin SD_MEASURE\n   G12_dfd_dfjs Dngs_sdfFvsUPds\n  skhfSdf_Sdf SDFsSDf_SFs_Sf   /end SD_MEASURE\n**  **/begin SDF_MEASURE\n   sfDS_dsfsCs DSFS_Dss\n DSfAv_Adfs_S   /end SDF_MEASURE\n** "22.1.10"\n/end FUNCTION\n/begin Za%adnwindter" /" SYBOLE_LINK /begin SD_LDJF\n   G_dfd_dfjs Dngs_sdfFvsUPds\n   /end SD_LDJF\n ASDV_sdl  **/begin JF_MEASURE\n   sdkS_dfd_dfjs DngsSs_sdfFvsUPds\n   /end JF_MEASURE** lds;a/n  skfjo_dflsSDFFs,.;l,']'].,[/;.12334s fdfss'''

```
   doc_string = '''Unwanted_Strings(Un_wanted_Data)->'UNWANTED_DATA "22.1.10"\n/end FUNCTION\n/begin Za%adnwindter" /" SYBOLE_LINK AXINW_Pdroc_ScjfdS1 */\n /begin SER_SDVKHSDF\n   CDLWKJFL lfjd\n   dkjfJJJJJJJJJJJJk_lfkgj\n /end /begin SD_MEASURE\n   G12_dfd_dfjs Dngs_sdfFvsUPds\n  skhfSdf_Sdf SDFsSDf_SFs_Sf   /end SD_MEASURE\n  /begin SDF_MEASURE\n   sfDS_dsfsCs DSFS_Dss\n DSfAv_Adfs_S   /end SDF_MEASURE\n "22.1.10"\n/end FUNCTION\n/begin Za%adnwindter" /" SYBOLE_LINK /begin SD_LDJF\n   G_dfd_dfjs Dngs_sdfFvsUPds\n   /end SD_LDJF\n ASDV_sdl   /begin JF_MEASURE\n   sdkS_dfd_dfjs DngsSs_sdfFvsUPds\n   /end JF_MEASURE lds;a/n  skfjo_dflsSDFFs,.;l,']'\].,[/;.12334s fdfss'''
```

In the above whole string need to detect only these below string, highlighted in paragraph:

1. key words: /begin SOMETEXT_MEASURE    datas   /end SOMETEXT_MEASURE (begin MEASURE capture_data end MEASURE)
2. need to remove \n in data (Dngs_sdfFvsUPds\n) Dngs_sdfFvsUPds

Datas needed:

```
/begin SD_MEASURE\n   G12_dfd_dfjs Dngs_sdfFvsUPds\n  skhfSdf_Sdf SDFsSDf_SFs_Sf /end SD_MEASURE
/begin SDF_MEASURE\n   sfDS_dsfsCs DSFS_Dss\n DSfAv_Adfs_S   /end SDF_MEASURE
/begin JF_MEASURE\n   sdkS_dfd_dfjs DngsSs_sdfFvsUPds\n   /end JF_MEASURE
```

Not needed formates (MEASURE word not in this after /begin and after /end):

```
/begin SD_LDJF\n   G_dfd_dfjs Dngs_sdfFvsUPds\n   /end SD_LDJF
```

I tried basic regex,split,findall methods but can't get the output since it has special chars and spaces:

```
result = re.findall('begin(.*?)end', string)
```

expected output:

```
[['G12_dfd_dfjs', 'Dngs_sdfFvsUPds', 'skhfSdf_Sdf', 'SDFsSDf_SFs_Sf'], ['sfDS_dsfsCs','DSFS_Dss','DSfAv_Adfs_S'], ['sdkS_dfd_dfjs','DngsSs_sdfFvsUPds']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lXq17O/1)):

```py
import re

doc_string = """Unwanted_Strings(Un_wanted_Data)->'UNWANTED_DATA "22.1.10"\n/end FUNCTION\n/begin Za%adnwindter" /" SYBOLE_LINK AXINW_Pdroc_ScjfdS1 */\n /begin SER_SDVKHSDF\n   CDLWKJFL lfjd\n   dkjfJJJJJJJJJJJJk_lfkgj\n /end /begin SD_MEASURE\n   G12_dfd_dfjs Dngs_sdfFvsUPds\n  skhfSdf_Sdf SDFsSDf_SFs_Sf   /end SD_MEASURE\n  /begin SDF_MEASURE\n   sfDS_dsfsCs DSFS_Dss\n DSfAv_Adfs_S   /end SDF_MEASURE\n "22.1.10"\n/end FUNCTION\n/begin Za%adnwindter" /" SYBOLE_LINK /begin SD_LDJF\n   G_dfd_dfjs Dngs_sdfFvsUPds\n   /end SD_LDJF\n ASDV_sdl   /begin JF_MEASURE\n   sdkS_dfd_dfjs DngsSs_sdfFvsUPds\n   /end JF_MEASURE lds;a/n  skfjo_dflsSDFFs,.;l,']'\].,[/;.12334s fdfss"""


out = []
for m in re.finditer(
    r"/begin (.+?)_MEASURE\s*(.*?)\s*/end \1_MEASURE", doc_string, flags=re.S
):
    out.append(m.group(2).split())

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    ["G12_dfd_dfjs", "Dngs_sdfFvsUPds", "skhfSdf_Sdf", "SDFsSDf_SFs_Sf"],
    ["sfDS_dsfsCs", "DSFS_Dss", "DSfAv_Adfs_S"],
    ["sdkS_dfd_dfjs", "DngsSs_sdfFvsUPds"],
]
```

Comment: what data m.group(2) contains if the data increases it will work?

Comment: @Kumar `m.group(2)` contains the string from the second capturing group. `m.group(1)` is the string from first group - in this case the string before _MEASURE